# R shiny passing column name in paste function

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app, where i need to pass the column names through selectInput. However when i pass the variable name to a paste function it is considering
as text instead of a variable/column name.

lets say i have dataframe i.e. df3

```
df3 <- data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=c(1:10),c=c(1:10),d=c(1:10),e=c(1:10),f=c(1:10),g=c(1:10))

ID  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

using selectInput i will pass the columns e , f, g dynamically based on my requirement

```
selectInput("columns1","Select the 1st Filter Variable:", choices = colnames)}})

df3$concate1 <- with(df3, (paste0(a,'+',b,'+',c,'+',input$columns1))
```

when i pass the variable 'e' the variable name is substituted but not the values in column 'e' i.e.

```
ID concate1
1  1+1+1+e
2  2+2+2+e
3  3+3+3+e
```

I need to get the values of column 'e' in the df3$concate1 in the below manner. plz help me in resolving this.

```
ID concate1
1  1+1+1+1
2  2+2+2+2
3  3+3+3+3
```

Comment: Are these colnames coming from some dataframe. if yes, can you please give the particular df and how the code on how are you passing the same here. Basically, I want to see how your choices is getting filled with the colnames of the particular dataframe

Comment: You'll need to enclose `input$columns1` by get to get the value as variable, like: `get(input$columns1)`

Comment: Yes the column names are from the same dataframe. I am creating a concatenate variable (cancate1) inorder to fetch the data from the other data frame.

Comment: I already tried using get(input$columns1) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

df3 <- data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=c(1:10),c=c(1:10),d=c(1:10),e=c(1:10),f=c(1:10),g=c(1:10))


ui <-  shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(
  selectInput("columns1","Select the 1st Filter Variable:", colnames(df3),colnames(df3[1])),
  textOutput("selection")
)
)
)


server <- function(input, output){  

  output$selection <- renderText({
    column = (input$columns1);
    columnElement = which(colnames(df3) == column)
    df3$concate1 <- with(df3, (paste0(a,'+',b,'+',c,'+',columnElement)))
  })


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However my requirement is to get the attributes in that passing column (input$columns1) and not the variable/column name.

Comment: If I understood correctly from your above comment, please find my edited answer

Comment: From my above code, i need to get the values of passing variable. let say i am passing a variable called input$columns1 i.e.'BRANDS' - which has different brands as values so when i concatenate with other columns the vector dt1temp$concate1 should have the value in below mentioned way.  (1st row.) Philippines+2016+21+MALE+brandX     (2nd row) Malaysia+2013+47+MALE+brandY    (3rd row) Greece+2013+49+FEMALE+brandZ

Comment: I still can't understand your problem, Can you please put a sample dataframe of yours, so that I can correctly visualize what you really want

Comment: Edited the answer as you want. It will work as you have asked.

Comment: @chary: I hope the edited answer has solved your problem